# can we access sharepoint list items through object model when current login user have read permissions?

Tags: sharepoint, object, model

iam using sharepoint object model to access the sharepoint list items.when iam login to the site with fullcontrol permission it is working fine.but when iam login with read permission(user) it is not working.

please tell me can we access the list items with read permission user through object model.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can only read values, but this is possible. Post the non-working code if you want more help.